# ERROR: Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin is problem

Tags: android-studio-3.3

after updating android studio up
version 3.3 crashes this error, please help
ERROR: Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin

Answer (score 3):

In general, to solve this problem, go to File> Build, Execution, Deployment> Gradle> Android Studio in android studio
there tick enable embedded maven repository after clicking Apply and then grudle rebuild and this error will disappear

Answer (score 1):

I reboot my computer and it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

If there are plugins specified in the project's gradle build files, check that they have been upgraded